# AR Aging DAX Pattern

Tags: powerpivot, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a measure that displays buckets of AR values from our accounting system. The billing table is structured in a way where a row is created for each financial transaction related to a bill: one record shows the billed amount and a separate record, related by a bill key, shows one or more payments to the bill. I am able to create multiple measures that sum the bill amounts and break these out by Current, 30, 60, 90 and 120 day buckets (admittedly, this is new to me so even this measure might not be right):

```
AR Current = 
VAR EndDate = TODAY()
VAR StartDate = EndDate - 29
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [Billings], 
    DATESBETWEEN(
        'Date'[Date],  StartDate, EndDate
    )
)
```

The issue I have is trying to sum up the collections. The collections are not aged, but the total amounts collected for a specific bill need to be subtracted from the total billings in each aging bucket. Regardless of the date range, I need to get a list of all Bill Keys for each bucket, use those keys to sum the values for the Collections column, and subtract from the total within a bucket.

The only equivalent I can think of is a SQL query:

```
--This example gets the billed amount for anything less than 30 days old)
SELECT BILLKEY, SUM(BILLAMOUNT) BILLAMOUNT
FROM tblBilling
WHERE BILLDATE BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY BILLKEY

-- This gets the corresponding collections:
SELECT BILLKEY, SUM(COLECTION) COLLECTION
FROM tblBilling
WHERE BILLKEY IN (
    SELECT BILLKEY FROM tblBillings WHERE BILLDATE BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND GETDATE()
)
GROUP BY BILLKEY
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Could you add a sample of your data? A more ilustrative example of your expected result could be very useful to provide an answer.